# Is it possible to define a function property on an object literal in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I would like to have the property (*server*) on function (*first*) defined directly in the object literal (*actions*).

```
var actions = {
    first: function(){
        console.log("First")
    },
    second: function(){
        console.log("Second")
    },
};
actions.first.server = "server_1";
```

Comment: I think its possible. Check this..http://jsfiddle.net/Wyrcz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a function when in doubt, or anytime you want to use a complex construct where a variable is expected:

```
var actions = {

    first: (function(){ 

         function first(){
              console.log("First")
         }; 

         first.server="server_1"; 
         return first; 
     }()),

    second: function(){
        console.log("Second")
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### FunctionDecorator

Pass your function as a context to a class/decorator -- or -- add the property deliberately:

```
function FunctionDecorator(server) { this.server = server; return this; }
var object = {
    first: FunctionDecorator.call(function first() {}, 'server_1')
};
```

-- OR --

```
var object = {
    first: function first() { first.server = first.server || getServer(); }
};
```

However, I would say you could work more on some OOP as this is somewhat cludgey unless you want callable objects (using the decorator method). For instance, AngularJS has a `$http` module which can be used like `$http({...})` or `$http.get(...)` -- this is because its a decorated function.

Cheers